# RDF to XML transformation

Tags: xml, xslt, sparql, rdf

i want to convert RDF file to XML.

example :

```
aml:length  aml:hasDataType  "xs:double" ;
        aml:hasValue     "35"^^xsd:double ;
        rdf:type         aml:Attribute ;
        schema:name      "length" .
```

i want this to be transformed in to XML :

```
<Attribute Name="length" DataType="xs:double">
                <Value>35</Value>
            </Attribute>
```

i have the ontology file which i can use to describe while reading the rdf and then use it to construct the RDF.

MY question is what is the best approach to convert to XML. i am using apache jena to process the RDF. So my RDF is available in every format.

1-  Use XML stylesheet to convert into XML.

2-  Read the rdf triple by triple , do describe/ask query on ontology and then try to construct XML tags.

Thankyou for help.

Comment: RDF has a serialization format (which you do not really have much control on) call RDF/XML. If you want full control on the output format and use Jena the easiest is probably to use a lib for creating XML documents (one you know) and use methods on the jena Model class. Methods like listStatements can help here.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is probably to transform the RDF to RDF/XML with class/property names as XML elements, which would give you

```xml
<aml:Attribute>
  <aml:hasDataType>xs:double</aml:hasDataType>
  <aml:hasValue rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">35</aml:hasValue>
  <schema:name>length</schema:name>
</aml:Attribute>
```

Then you can transform this with XSLT to remove the namespaces, rename/remove/atrributize elements.

Make sure you don't use the `<rdf:Description>` variant of RDF/XML. In particular, if you have multiple `rdf:type` for a class, this will break. But for simple cases, RDF/XML + XSLT for RDF->XML is nice because it uses declarative syntax and is widely understood.

Comment: i have never used XSLT. can you give me a link where i can read about editing through XSLT.

Comment: Google `rdf2xml xslt` and similar. Search Github for XSLT files with rdf in them. There are also questions on SO for rdf+xml+xslt.